# No Man's Sky - Exocraft Tech bug

Tags: no-mans-sky

So i'm doing the Exocraft Tech missions and you have to make the three Geobays; Roamer, Nomad and Colossus - in that order. But somehow I managed to build the Colossus before the Nomad Geobay and now anytime I construct the Nomad bay it doesn't register.

Anyone else having this problem or just me? Or does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you try and remove the Colossus and build the Nomad first? I haven't built either, only the Roamer, and my current quest is to build the Colossus.

Comment: Thanks Thomas but when I tried this, it didn't work. I don't think it worked because the Nomad and Colossus had already spawned. Is there a way to de-spawn the vehicles in NMS?

Comment: Sadly I don't know. Which quest do you have now?

Comment: I have "Construct a Nomad Geobay" but as I said, I have made it along with the Colossus Geobay.

Comment: It took a couple of days - mainly because I haven't been on. It was as simple as building the Nomad bay on another planet.

Comment: That's weird. I just built the Nomad yesterday after the Colossus too and the quest passed just fine. Good thing you solved it. Maybe you should post that as an answer for the next person that comes across this bug.